# LINQ　複数テーブルjoinと複合条件とwhere

Tags: c#, sql, linq

下のSQLクエリをLINQにしたいのですが、複雑過ぎて途中で分からなくなってしまいました。

```sql
    SELECT
                [ID],
                [DATE],
                [NO],
                [DSP_NO],
                (CASE v1.[RTth] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE 'R'+v1.[RTth] END) +
                (CASE v2.[LTth] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE 'L'+v2.[LTth] END) +
                (CASE v3.[RTth] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE 'r'+v3.[RTth] END) +
                (CASE v4.[LTth] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE 'l'+v4.[LTth] END) AS [BI], 
                ISNULL((CASE c1.[NAME_1]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b1.[BCD]  END) +
                (CASE c1.[NAME_2]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b2.[BCD]  END) +
                (CASE c1.[NAME_3]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b3.[BCD]  END) +
                (CASE c1.[NAME_4]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b4.[BCD]  END) +
                (CASE c1.[NAME_5]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b5.[BCD]  END) +
                (CASE c1.[NAME_6]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b6.[BCD]  END) +
                (CASE c1.[NAME_7]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b7.[BCD]  END) +
                (CASE c1.[NAME_8]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b8.[BCD]  END) +
                (CASE c2.[NAME_9]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b9.[BCD]  END) +
                (CASE c2.[NAME_10] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b10.[BCD] END) +
                (CASE c2.[NAME_11] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b11.[BCD] END) +
                (CASE c2.[NAME_12] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b12.[BCD] END) +
                (CASE c2.[NAME_13] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b13.[BCD] END) +
                (CASE c2.[NAME_14] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b14.[BCD] END) +
                (CASE c2.[NAME_15] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b15.[BCD] END) +
                (CASE c2.[NAME_16] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b16.[BCD] END) , '') AS [NAME_ID]
                FROM Table3 AS k1
                LEFT JOIN Table1 AS v1 ON k1.[UR] = v1.[NoFlg]
                LEFT JOIN Table1 AS v2 ON k1.[UL] = v2.[NoFlg]
                LEFT JOIN Table1 AS v3 ON k1.[DR] = v3.[NoFlg]
                LEFT JOIN Table1 AS v4 ON k1.[DL] = v4.[NoFlg]
                LEFT JOIN table4 AS c1 ON k1.[TOUROKU_1] = c1.[TOUROKU_NO]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b1  ON k1.[ID] = b1.[ID]  AND c1.[NAME_1]  = b1.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b1.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b1.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b2  ON k1.[ID] = b2.[ID]  AND c1.[NAME_2]  = b2.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b2.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b2.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b3  ON k1.[ID] = b3.[ID]  AND c1.[NAME_3]  = b3.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b3.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b3.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b4  ON k1.[ID] = b4.[ID]  AND c1.[NAME_4]  = b4.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b4.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b4.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b5  ON k1.[ID] = b5.[ID]  AND c1.[NAME_5]  = b5.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b5.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b5.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b6  ON k1.[ID] = b6.[ID]  AND c1.[NAME_6]  = b6.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b6.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b6.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b7  ON k1.[ID] = b7.[ID]  AND c1.[NAME_7]  = b7.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b7.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b7.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b8  ON k1.[ID] = b8.[ID]  AND c1.[NAME_8]  = b8.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b8.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b8.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN table5 AS c2 ON k1.[TOUROKU_2] = c2.[TOUROKU_NO]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b9  ON k1.[ID] = b9.[ID]  AND c2.[NAME_9]  = b9.[TOUROKU_NO]  AND k1.[DATE] >= b9.[START_DATE]  AND k1.[DATE] < b9.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b10 ON k1.[ID] = b10.[ID] AND c2.[NAME_10] = b10.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b10.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b10.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b11 ON k1.[ID] = b11.[ID] AND c2.[NAME_11] = b11.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b11.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b11.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b12 ON k1.[ID] = b12.[ID] AND c2.[NAME_12] = b12.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b12.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b12.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b13 ON k1.[ID] = b13.[ID] AND c2.[NAME_13] = b13.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b13.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b13.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b14 ON k1.[ID] = b14.[ID] AND c2.[NAME_14] = b14.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b14.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b14.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b15 ON k1.[ID] = b15.[ID] AND c2.[NAME_15] = b15.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b15.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b15.[END_DATE]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b16 ON k1.[ID] = b16.[ID] AND c2.[NAME_16] = b16.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b16.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b16.[END_DATE]
```

次のようにクエリ式で書いてみたのですが、join句のいずれかの式の型が正しくありません。
というエラーが出てしまいます。

```
    var q = from em in Table3
                    join thUR in Table1 on em.UR equals thUR.RTth
                    join thUL in Table1 on em.UL equals thUL.LTth
                    join thDr in Table1 on em.DR equals thDr.RTth
                    join thDl in Table1 on em.DL equals thDl.LTth
                    join HK in table4 on em.TOUROKU_1 equals HK.TOUROKU_NO
          //この下のjoin句で対象のエラーが発生
                    join TB2 in Table2 on new { a = em.ID, b = HK.NAME_1} equals new { a = TB2.ID, b = TB2.TOUROKU_NO} into g
                    where em.DATE >= g.START_DATE & em.DATE< g.END_DATE
                        select new {
                        em.ID,
                        em.DATE,
                        em.NO,
                        em.DSP_NO,
                        BI = (thUR.RTth == "0" ? "" : "R" + thUR.RTth) +
                              (thUL.LTth == "0" ? "" : "L" + thUL.LTth) +
                              (thDr.RTth == "0" ? "" : "r" + thDr.RTth) +
                              (thDl.LTth == "0" ? "" : "l" + thDl.LTth),
                        NAME_ID = (HK.NAME_1 == "0" ? "" : from c in g select c.BCD)
                    };
```

テーブル構成は次の通りです。

```
 Table1
    [NoFlg],
    [RTth],
    [LTth]    

Table2
[ID],
[START_DATE],    
[TOUROKU_NO],
[BCD],
[END_DATE]


Table3
[ID],
[DATE],
[NO],
[DSP_NO],
[UR],
[UL],
[DR],
[DL],
[TOUROKU_1],
[TOUROKU_2],
[TOUROKU_3],
[TOUROKU_4]

table4
[TOUROKU_NO],
[NAME_1],
[NAME_2],
[NAME_3],
[NAME_4],
[NAME_5],
[NAME_6],
[NAME_7],
[NAME_8],

table5
[TOUROKU_NO],
[NAME_9],
[NAME_10],
[NAME_11],
[NAME_12],
[NAME_13],
[NAME_14],
[NAME_15],
[NAME_16],
```

いろいろと試してみてはいますが、手詰まり状態です。
どなたかご回答いただける方よろしくお願いします。

Comment: multipost https://teratail.com/questions/52745

Comment: 本当に`LEFT JOIN`を実現したいのでしょうか？ 例えば`v1`は`SELECT`句にて行が存在することを前提とした式が書かれていますが？

Comment: はい、必ず入ってる事が前提で大丈夫です。

Comment: 「大丈夫です」でなく質問文を訂正してください。LEFT JOINとINNER JOINとでは想定するデータもそこから得られる結果も全く異なります。更に言えばINNER JOINも適切か疑問です。例えば結合される行が１行に確定しているのであればよりパフォーマンスのよい書き方があります。ゴールとなるべきSQL文がこのような状況では、同じ結果となるLINQ文を書きようがありません。

Comment: INNER JOINはしなくていいです。提示したSQLをlinqにしたいです。今は@pgrhoさんの回答を見ながら作っていますが、不足なく取れそうですよ。ただ、今はそのlinqでデータを取得するときに処理がかかりすぎるので、早く処理ができるように考え中なのですが、なかなか難しいですね。

Comment: より適切な`INNER JOIN`でなく余計なオーバーヘッドのかかる`LEFT OUTER JOIN`で構わない、結果が不足なく得られればそれでよい、そのような考え方なのであればパフォーマンスを求めるべきではありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbSet`を使用して`Select`の中で副問い合わせを行えばよいのではないかと思います。

```
from em in Table3
join c1 in table4 on em.TOUROKU_1 equals c1.TOUROKU_NO
join c2 in table4 on em.TOUROKU_2 equals c2.TOUROKU_NO
select new
{
   em.ID,
   em.DATE,
   em.NO,
   em.DSP_NO,
   BI = Table1.Where(v => em.UR == v.NoFlg && v.RTth != "0").Select(v => "R" + v.RTth).FirstOrDefault()
       + Table1.Where(v => em.UL == v.NoFlg && v.LTth != "0").Select(v => "R" + v.LTth).FirstOrDefault()
       + Table1.Where(v => em.DR == v.NoFlg && v.RTth != "0").Select(v => "r" + v.RTth).FirstOrDefault()
       + Table1.Where(v => em.DL == v.NoFlg && v.LTth != "0").Select(v => "l" + v.LTth).FirstOrDefault(),
   NAME_ID = Table2.Where(v => em.ID == v.ID
                            && c1.NAME_1 == v.TOUROKU_NO
                            && v.TOUROKU_NO != "0"
                            && em.DATE >= v.START_DATE
                            && em.DATE < v.END_DATE)
                    .Select(v => v.BCD)
                    .FirstOrDefault() // b1
            + Table2.Where(v => em.ID == v.ID
                            && c1.NAME_2 == v.TOUROKU_NO
                            && v.TOUROKU_NO != "0"
                            && em.DATE >= v.START_DATE
                            && em.DATE < v.END_DATE)
                    .Select(v => v.BCD) // b2
                    .FirstOrDefault()
 // TODO:b3-b16を追加する
}
```

ただ上記の方針で生成されるクエリーの効率が良いかどうかは分かりません。もしログ出力を確認して問題があるのであれば、`Database.SqlQuery<TItem>`を使用することもできます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。上記の

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。すみません。Table1.Where(v => em.UR == v.NoFlg && v.RTth != "0").Select(v => "R" + v.RTth).FirstOrDefault()の部分ではなく join HK in table4 on em.TOUROKU_1 equals HK.TOUROKU_NO
          //この下のjoin句で対象のエラーが発生
                    join TB2 in Table2 on new { a = em.ID, b = HK.NAME_1} equals new { a = TB2.ID, b = TB2.TOUROKU_NO} into g
                    where em.DATE >= g.START_DATE & em.DATE< g.END_DATEでエラーが出てしまっております。続きも教えていただけますでしょうか？

Comment: SQLで言うところの LEFT JOIN table4 AS c1 ON k1.[TOUROKU_1] = c1.[TOUROKU_NO]
                LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b1  ON k1.[ID] = b1.[ID]  AND c1.[NAME_1]  = b1.[TOUROKU_NO] AND k1.[DATE] >= b1.[START_DATE] AND k1.[DATE] < b1.[END_DATE]になります。

Comment: 多少追記しました。上記の方針でEFクエリーを書けなくはないですが、Table2部分だけでも別のクエリーに分割したほうが分かりやすくなると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: まだ試していませんがひとつ質問です。   && v.TOUROKU_NO != "0"の部分はSQLで言うとこのCASE c1.[NAME_1]  WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE b1.[BCD]  END)を簡略化したということでしょうか？

Comment: はい。c1.NAME_1にしていない理由は単にコピペしやすいからです。

Comment: こんにちわ。クエリは発行できたのですが、今そのクエリの結果を取得するのに手間取っています。foreachでクエリの結果を追加しているのですが、１万件程度だと２，３分ぐらいで終わるのですが、４万件ほどになると１時間以上かかってしまいます。単純に考えて４倍だとしても８～１２分程で終わっていいものだと思っていたのですが、何が問題なのかがわかりません。foreach以外で何か高速に処理する方法などご存じでしたらご教授いただけると助かります。

Comment: List<DataClass> dataList = new List<DataClass>();
   DataClass kdcc = new DataClass();
     
   foreach (var item in em) {
    kdcc.ID = item.ID;
    kdcc.DATE = item.DATE;
    kdcc.NO = item.NO;
    kdcc.DSP_NO = item.DSP_NO;
    kdcc.BI = item.BI;
    kdcc.NAME_ID = item.NAME_ID.ToString();
    dataList.Add(kdcc);
   }

Comment: 少し見にくいですが、上のコードがリンクの結果の取得で使っているコードです。よろしくお願いします。